# No email sent from VSTS after each release

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS is there an option to send email after a release is done. For build when build is done success or fail we get automated email. I see no option for release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify in Notification page. Detail steps as below:

In Notification settings page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_usersSettings/notifications#) -> New subscription -> select Release A deployment is completed template -> Next -> (specify filters if you want) -> Finish.

[image]

Then you will receive email notifications after a deployment finished.

Comment: In VSTS Project Settings>Notifications